# Core Data one to many relationship get Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am storing JSON Data to CoreData with a one-to-many relationship. I am able to get the data back, using NSFetchRequest and fast enumeration, but the data is not coming in the order format I need and it cannot be used in my UITableViewCells how can i do this
this is my code
this is my datamodel 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1e1ujrjxtkjy9h9/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-29%20at%205.14.31%20pm.png?dl=0

```
_appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [_appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DealSection"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sectionID == %@",_sectionID]];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSArray * sortDescriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptor];
    NSError * error;
    NSArray * data = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    _fetchData = data;


    for (DealSection * section in _fetchData) {
        for (Deal * deal in [section alldeals]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[deal nameAttribute]);
        }
    }
```

i put this all code in the ViewDidLoad

here am getting the data from NSLog but my problem am able to print the data but am not able to pass the data to the table view

Comment: is there any other way to get the data

Comment: I think you might have defined your relationships the wrong way round.  It looks like `Deal.sectionRelation` is "to-many", shouldn't it be "to-one"?  And the inverse, `DealSection.alldeals` is "to-one", shouldn't it be "to-many"?

Comment: but deal is not only one type i mean not may be one deal belongs to many sections because my JSON response have sections as array and objects are dininig , travel..... like this so i think to take to many relationships

Comment: The screenshot of your data model implies that one deal has many sections, and each section has only one deal.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: that means i have to use many to many relation ?

Comment: because i have 1 deal which belongs to 2 or 3 sections

Comment: and section will many deals so finally i have to use many to many relationship is that you telling ?

Comment: Hi please connect me with skype mahesh_m04 it is very important to me please

Comment: Sorry, no Skype.  But yes, it sounds like you need many-many relationship.  Can you edit your post to show some of the JSON, and the code where you store it to CoreData?

Comment: http://pastie.org/10123389

Comment: this is the JSON one record

Comment: see the code i edited above am saving data to core data and please see that am i doing any thing wrong with the relationships

Comment: i have section , benefit , location  where i have to create the to --> many relation ship is that am doing wright or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON snippet that you have posted shows that (contrary to my supposition in the comments, apologies) each `Deal` can have many `DealSections`.

Your `DealSection` entity has a relationship entitled `alldeals` that is currently a to-one relationship.  I.e. each `DealSection` can have only one `Deal`.  I think this should be to-many.  To take an example, the deal in the JSON you posted has sections with ID=6 (name="Services") and ID=8 (name="Wellness").  Suppose you had another deal with a section with ID=6 - do you want to use establish the relationship with the existing `DealSection`, or to create a new `DealSection`?

Currently your code creates a new `DealSection`, but I think you probably want the relationship with the existing `DealSection`.  For that to work, you will need to

a) amend your data model to make the relationship many-many.

b) amend the code where you store the data for the many-many relationship, so that it starts by trying to fetch a `DealSection` with the correct ID.  If one is found, add that `DealSection` to the Deal's `sectionRelation`.  If it is not found, created a new `DealSection` and add that to the `Deal`.

**EDIT**

To display the data in a tableView, you need to implement three datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // A table view section for each DealSection:
    return [self.fetchData count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    DealSection *dealSection = self.fetchData[section];
    NSArray *deals = [dealSection.alldeals allObjects];
    return [deals count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Amend this identifier to match your cell prototype 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Set up the cell...
    DealSection *dealSection = (DealSection *)self.fetchData[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *deals = [dealSection.alldeals allObjects];
    Deal *deal = (Deal *)deals[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = deal.nameAttribute;
    return cell;
}
```

This is basic table view stuff, so if any of it is unclear I recommend the tutorial I mentioned in comments.

Comment: so that means Deal<-many to many->DealSection is that i need to do

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0w0jwatk8ppg6e/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-01%20at%204.55.15%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: i changed the data model but why we need this methods                                - (void)addAlldealsObject:(Deal *)value;
- (void)removeAlldealsObject:(Deal *)value;
- (void)addAlldeals:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeAlldeals:(NSSet *)values;   which came in the DealSection Entity

Comment: and the way am storing the data to DealSection is Correct or i am doing any mistake in this

Comment: No there will be only Unique ID for Sections (ID will not repeat again as you said example ID = 6)

Comment: Hey data is coming perfectly But the problem is Data is coming in the fast enumeration which i have to show in the tableview How can i show the data coming from fast enumeration to tableViewCells can i add those data to array and show or what i have to do ....

Comment: Domino's Pizza
Yo! China
Great Kabab Factory
Nom Nom
Zerruco
Sahib Sindh Sultan
The Aquarium Lounge 
Smokey's BBQ & Grill
7 Degrees Brauhaus
Imperfecto

Comment: this way data is coming

Comment: please help me with this core data i am stuck on this for nearly 10 days i am not getting any better help

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you just want help to display the data in a tableView, I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) - specifically the section entitled "Creating a table view"

Comment: please see the edited question am getting data by printing in fast enumeration but how to store the data and display in the tableview

Comment: Love you man thank you soo much it is working my 10 days work you made me in 1 hour thank you soo much